# "Copy" option missing from Safari Desktop Web Share API?

Tags: safari, web-share

I am trying to implement the Web Share API for some text I want to allow users to copy/share, and it's been successful except for an issue with Safari desktop. I check for `navigator.share` and if it exists, then only do I open the native share screen, and if it doesn't, I just copy the text straight to clipboard (like on desktop).

Safari desktop DOES support the Web Share API, however it doesn't seem to provide a way to just copy it? You can see in the screenshot it just gives some options for me. Am I missing something? Is there no way to have "Copy" as an option?

```
const copyURL = copyText => {
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator
    .share({ text: copyText })
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(console.error);
} else {
  navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then(result => {
    if (result.state === 'granted' || result.state === 'prompt') {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText).then(() => {
        setLinkCopied(true);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

};

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed no "Copy" feature in desktop Safari's share sheet. The good news is that Safari supports the [Async Clipboard API](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/), so you can easily use it as an alternative, as shown in the example below:

```js
async function copyPageUrl() {
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(location.href);
    console.log('Page URL copied to clipboard');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
  }
}
```

Comment: But why doesn't Safari include the "Copy Link" feature in the share sheet despite the fact that it is enabled in the preferences? Is it intentional or due to a bug?

Comment: I am not a Safari engineer, but I suppose they simply haven’t gotten to implement it. Maybe file a feature request at https://bugs.webkit.org/.